# Divide the SUM of two integers and return a Float in Python/Django

Tags: python, django

I've spent long time trying to return a Float result from the division of Sum(value1) and Sum(value2)

Here's my code:

```
kpiCapaTotal = reportKpiCeFilter.aggregate(kpiCapaTotal=Sum('operation_time') / Sum('load_time') * 100).get('kpiCapaTotal')
```

It returns: 89,0 but the correct should be 89,3

I tried :

```
kpiCapaTotal = reportKpiCeFilter.annotate(kpiCapaTotal=Sum('operation_time') / Cast(Sum('load_time'),FloatField()) * 100, output_field=FloatField()).get('kpiCapaTotal')
```

It returns an error:

> "QuerySet.annotate() received non-expression(s):
> <django.db.models.fields.FloatField>."

Also with aggregate:

```
kpiCapaTotal = reportKpiCeFilter.aggregate(kpiCapaTotal=Sum('operation_time') / Cast(Sum('load_time'),FloatField()) * 100,output_field=FloatField()).get('kpiCapaTotal')
```

Error:

> "QuerySet.aggregate() received non-expression(s):
> <django.db.models.fields.FloatField>."

I'dont know how to divide the SUM of two integers and return a Float, do you have any idea?
Python Version: 3.7
Djando Version: 2.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a slight mistake in your second and third attempt:

```
Cast(Sum('load_time'),FloatField())
```

You need to pass `FloatField()` as a keyword argument `output_field`:

```
Cast(Sum('load_time'), output_field=FloatField())
```

Also you can't pass `output_field=FloatField()` to `annotate` or `aggregate`.

Also since you cast only one part of the expression (the other parts are of different types) you need to use [`ExpressionWrapper` [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/expressions/#expressionwrapper-expressions) to set the `output_field`.

Hence your query would be:

```
from django.db.models import ExpressionWrapper

kpiCapaTotal = reportKpiCeFilter.aggregate(
    kpiCapaTotal=ExpressionWrapper(
        Sum('operation_time') / Cast(
            Sum('load_time'), output_field=FloatField()
        ) * 100,
        output_field=FloatField()
    )
).get('kpiCapaTotal')
```

Comment: Hello Mr. Barkat, thank you for your answer, it returned the follow error: Expression contains mixed types. You must set output_field"

Comment: Thank you @Abdul Aziz Barkat, I've looking for this solution for much time, it definetely solved my problem.